# How to count the number of all the possible binary sub strings of a given length?

Tags: java, arrays, performance, memory, out-of-memory

In the following code I am trying to count all the possible binary sub strings of length m within an array of binary numbers, which means there are 2^m possible sub strings that can be found within given binary array.

I have tried accomplishing the task using following approach:

```
byte [] E = {0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1}; 
int m=3;
int [] c = new int [(int)Math.pow(2,m)];

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
int g=0;
for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
{
g <<= 1;
if(E[i+j]==1)
g++;
}
c[g]++;  
}
for(int i=0;i<c.length;i++)
System.out.print("n("+i+")->"+c[i]+"     ");
```

Output:

```
n(0)->0     n(1)->1     n(2)->3     n(3)->1     n(4)->1     n(5)->3     n(6)->1     n(7)->0
```

The above approach requires 2^m memory to be allocated to array 'c' which will generate **OutOfMemoryError** for a large value of m (say m=30).

My questions:

1.Is there any better approach to avoid such error since the value of m might be very large and memory allocation might not be allowed?

2.How can I test accurately, if the memory allocation to the array is possible prior to actual allocation,
I have already tried using

```
if (Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() < ((Integer.SIZE/8)* Math.pow(2, m))) throw new Exception("value of m too large");
```

to check the available memory but it throws exception when m is between 21 and 25 where as the actual allocation takes place (without using above test condition) for m < 25.

Is my approach correct?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary instead of an array, and allocate the entries lazily. While that has a lot more overhead per entry, you will have far fewer than 2<sup>m</sup> entries especially when `m` gets big, because there are only `n-m+1` substrings of length `m` in a string of length `n`. So you might have `n-m+1` entries (which for even moderate `m` is much better than 2<sup>m</sup>), but only if E has a special structure, usually there will be fewer.

Comment: In `Java` this is a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're asking a different question from the math posted

If you're trying to get consecutive portions of size 3 (A) from an array of size 6 (B), there are 4 substrings you could possibly get (B - A + 1)

Main array

`BBBBBB`

Sub arrays

`AAABBB`

`BAAABB`

`BBAAAB`

`BBBAAA`